# 'touch' a file in Azure storage so that it is reprocessed by an Azure blog storage trigger function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-storage

I have an Azure function that runs based on an Azure blob storage trigger.  I am wondering if it's possible to somehow mark a file that has previously triggered my Azure function to be reprocessed by the function.  Would soft-deleting and then restoring the file work to re-trigger my function, for example? Is there a more canonical way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the [blob trigger official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp):

> The Blob storage trigger starts a function when a new or updated blob
> is detected.

If you want to retrigger the blob trigger and reprocess your blob, I think the most elegant way to do this is by adding metadata to your blob, this operation will be considered as an update action and fire the blob trigger.

I have tested on my local, when I add/update blob metadata, for instance,I add/update metadata `reprocess` with a timestamp, the trigger has been fired:

[image]
[image]